# HP Photosmart doing borderless printing of PDF

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, hp-photosmart

I am trying to print a PDF document which contains table with borders but my printer is not printing any borders.

I am using Mac with OSX 10.10 and my printer is HP photosmart 5520.I tried looking up at the configuration which might causing this issue but can't find anything. I also tried resetting the printer default setting but its not working!

Comment: I see you figured out a solution, but for the benefit of others who run into a similar problem, can you clarify the nature of the problem?  Is the printer in borderless photo print mode and the computer is over-cropping what it sends to the printer so the border is missing?  Are you using full-sized paper?  Are you using any customized print settings, like zoom to fit?  Can you provide more detail on the document, the PDF software you are printing from, the PDF software and print driver settings, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the printer settings for the pdf using printer dialog box:

- In the printer dialog box, selected the advance print setup.
- In Color management, ticked the `Let printer manage the colours` option

and the borders start appearing again!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this works?  It seems like the last thing I would look at in relation to the problem you describe unless it's an odd problem like the table has a black border, the black ink is out, and the setting allows the printer to simulate black using colored inks.